# Core data model versioning issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I am using lightweight migration for core data versioning in my iPhone application, and i add new model version to core data and set this new version as a current version, then i start adding new attributes to the NEW model version, and i release the app for app store.

When users update the application it crash and never run.

I find the cause of the crash, which is when i add the attributes to new version model, these attributes also added to the previous model version, so when users updated the application, lightweight migration does not work correctly since the version in users application does not match that version in the update application.

My question is: how this issue happens ? why Xcode add the new attributes to previous model and current model instead of adding it to current model only?

Comment: You do create a new data model version in XCode, right?

Comment: Yes exactly, i create the data model version in xcode

Comment: Did you pass options that enable lightweight migrations for the store coordinator?

Comment: Yes I did, the problem is when i add new attributes to new data model version, these attributes added also to the previous data model version, and the result is the new attributes are exist in both new model version and the previous model version

Comment: I mean, in Xcode. Select the data model and Editor->Add Model Version. It should create a new file. There's no reason it would add it to the previous version (the other files), they are two physically different files. Feel free to post a screenshot.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BzRX2T-BHn-4cVE2aHotWUdxUWM

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BzRX2T-BHn-4SmZwRGNYMEpNRzA

these screenshots links

Comment: may be Xcode hang up while it trying to link these data model files, resulting in this issue, what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May me some error occurred while Xcode linking core data models files